# C# Replace character every other word

Tags: c#

Recently I've been given an assignment to swap out let's say X for Y every other word, all the documentation I've found seems to contradict this possibility. I don't want a "Direct Answer" I'd like to exercise and learn it on my own, however if possible could someone give me a simplified example.

Such as Replace all A's with Z's every other word.

The way my program is structured is it will ask for user input use .split, and store each word into a separate "index" in an array.

Regards, and thank you MrJ

Comment: mystring.Replace('A', 'Z');

Comment: Its not very clear what you are asking.  If you don't have any code to post, at least give us psuedo code so we can try to help direct you.

Comment: Start simpler and work your way up to the complete solution.  Can you write code that would replace X for Y in **every** word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace every "A" with "Z" in a word, you can use this line:

```
s.Replace("A", "Z");
```

If you have an array of strings, you can just iterate over the array, and replace A's with Z's for every string:

```
string[] array = ...
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    array[i] = array[i].Replace("A", "Z");
```

Then, finally, if you only want to do this for every other string, just increase `i` by 2 each time, instead of 1:

```
string[] array = ...
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i += 2)
    array[i] = array[i].Replace("A", "Z");
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're on the right track. I would split on spaces to get all the words into an array. Then for-loop over the array and, where the index modulo 2 = 1 or 0 (depending on whether you want to alter even or odd words), use the char overload of replace .replace('x', 'y') to change your words. Then you just put the sentence back together